# NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7649/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

Tags: angular, gulp, systemjs

I stuck in an issue when using angular2 with asp.net core mvc project.
I have the following in my layout page

```html
    <script src="~/lib/core-js/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/zone.js/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/reflect-metadata/reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/systemjs/system.src.js"></script>


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){console.error(err + ' no idea what is going on')})
    </script>
```

I used the following gulp to copy the angular files to the wwwroot folder.

```html
/*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/

var gulp = require('gulp');
var libs = './wwwroot/lib/';


gulp.task('restore:core-js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/core-js/client/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'core-js'));
});

gulp.task('restore:zone.js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'zone.js'));
});

gulp.task('restore:reflect-metadata', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'reflect-metadata'));
});

gulp.task('restore:systemjs', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'systemjs'));
});

gulp.task('restore:rxjs', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'rxjs'));
});

gulp.task('restore:angular-in-memory-web-api', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'angular-in-memory-web-api'));
});

gulp.task('restore:angular', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + '@angular'));
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task('restore:bootstrap', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*.*'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'bootstrap'));
});

gulp.task('restore', [
    'restore:core-js',
    'restore:zone.js',
    'restore:reflect-metadata',
    'restore:systemjs',
    'restore:rxjs',
    'restore:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    'restore:angular',
    'restore:bootstrap'
]);
```

My systemjs.config.js is as follows:

```html
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',

            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            //'@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api'
        },

        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

And package.json is shown below

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"    
  }
}
```

And tsconfig.json is as shown below:

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

And finally my typings.json is

```html
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.9.0+20170324193834",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170322231424"
  }
}
```

I'm using typescript v 2.2.2.0

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're moving your @angular libraries from node_modules folder to wwwroot/libs.

I suggest changing this in your systemjs.config.js:

```
paths: {
    'npm:': 'libs/'
},
```

That will resolve your  @angular dependencies. You may want to add another path if you are moving node packages to a folder other than 'libs/'.

Comment: That explains my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works well on Firefox, Chrome and Edge but not on IE 11. Looking at the debugger, I got the following error:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'files' of undefined or null reference

Error: Syntax error
Evaluating http://localhost:7649/app/app.module.js 
Any ideas